# Updating label in main form from user control

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, user-controls, label

In my current application I have a `main form: frmMain` with a `statusstrip` and a `label: lblStatus` inside that.
I would like to update that label from inside my user controls, which I add to my main form when I click the concerning button:

```
ucBeheer ucBeheer = new ucBeheer();
splitContainer1.Panel2.Controls.Add(ucBeheer);
```

From inside my `usercontrol` when I do an action, I would like to update `lblStatus`. I have tried adding the following property to my main form:

```
    public string updateStatus
    {
        get { return lblStatus.Text; }
        set { lblStatus.Text = value; }
    }
```

And then accessing the method like this in my user control:

```
        frmMain mainForm = new frmMain();
        mainForm.updateStatus = "This is a test";
```

But that doesn't work, I know that this is because I am making a new object of my `frmMain`, but I don't know how to solve this otherwise?

I have also found the [following way](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/179720-accessing-forms-controls-from-a-user-control/), with an `Event Handler` but I can't do that because my user control isn't actually in my mainForm yet, until I add it there with clicking on the button, so I don't have a reference to it.

So I'm kinda out of ideas, I hope somebody can help me.
Thanks,
Thomas

Edit: So I managed to do it the following way:

```
        frmMain owningForm = (frmMain)this.Parent.Parent.Parent.Parent;
        owningForm.updateStatus = "This is a test";
```

but `this.Parent.Parent.Parent.Parent...` doesn't really seem like good coding to me, is there any other way to get the most top parent?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could add a property like this to your usercontrol, with this you can access the frmMain that the usercontrol resides in.

```
public frmMain MainForm
{
    get
    {
        var parent = Parent;
        while (parent != null && (parent as frmMain) == null)
        {
            parent = parent.Parent;
        }
        return parent as frmMain;
    }
}
```

**UPDATE:**
If you just want the top most parent you could use something like this:

```
public Control TopMostParent
{
    get
    {
        var parent = Parent;
        while (parent.Parent != null)
        {
            parent = parent.Parent;
        }
        return parent;
    }
}
```

Or even make an extension method of that:

```
public static Control TopMostParent(this Control control)
{
    var parent = control.Parent;
    while (parent.Parent != null)
    {
        parent = parent.Parent;
    }
    return parent;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your control and form have to communicate, so one needs to "know" about the other. In real terms, this means giving a reference to one, to the other. So you have 2 options: either the control needs a reference to the form, or the form needs a reference to the control.

The way I would do this would be for the form to subscribe to an event published by the control. This is the form giving a reference to just one of its methods to the control.

```
class StatusChangedEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
}

partial class MyControl : UserControl
{
    public event EventHandler<StatusChangedEventArgs> StatusChanged = delegate { };

    public void RaiseStatusChanged( string message )
    {
        StatusChanged( this, new StatusChangedEventArgs { Text = "message" } );
    }
}
```

Then, in your form, subscribe to the event:

```
...
ucBeheer ucBeheer = new ucBeheer();
ucBeheer.StatusChanged += HandleStatusChanged;
splitContainer1.Panel2.Controls.Add(ucBeheer);
...

partial class MyForm : Form
{
    void HandleStatusChanged( object sender, StatusChangedEventArgs args )
    {
        lblStatus.Text = args.Text;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but I don't really understand how to implement this? Where would I put the class `StatusChangedEventArgs` and how would I make it able to get and set text from my label?

Comment: I've added a code sample. Just call `RaiseStatusChanged` when you need to in your control.

Comment: Thanks, this works in most of my forms but in some cases I add a `usercontrol` in a `usercontrol` and then this wouldn't work. (I'm unsure if adding a `usercontrol` in a `usercontrol` is good coding, but it's the only way I found to be able to navigate properly)

Comment: Then you have the same situation, but with a parent UserControl instead of a Form, so you can use the same technique. If you find your MyForm instance using Parent.Parent..., then your controls need to know about the implementation of MyForm, which doesn't sound right. YMMV.

Answer (score -1):

You can reference your application's main form using the `Application.OpenForms` `FormCollection` by name:

```cs
frmMain owningForm = (frmMain)Application.OpenForms["frmMain"];

owningForm.updateStatus = "This is a test";
```